# Extract all documentation block comments from javascript file

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a reliable, trusty way to extract all block comments from a javascript file that have loaded into memory as a string.

I see a ton of options online for using regular expressions, but I was looking for a more fail-proof solution.

Namely, using either esprima (http://esprima.org) or falafel(https://github.com/substack/node-falafel), is there a way to take in a string representing some javascript code, and extract all the block comments, and return an array where each entry in the array is a string representing a single block comment?

Also, in case it wasn't clear, I need the parsing to be done in javascript as well (javascript parsing javascript).

Thanks!

Comment: What does "a more fail-proof solution" mean? What's the problem with regular expressions?

Comment: They don't catch comments inside of strings, which shouldn't be considered comments

Answer (score 1):

Esprima has a good solution:

http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

Their "attach comments" option was exactly what I was looking for